# In Bootstrap FileStyle how do I use the full path?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap FileStyle (http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/) 
how can I use make it get the full path instead of only the file name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that the Bootstrap FileStyle plugin start from a standard input file element.

So you can get its value by:

```
$("input[type=file]").val();
```

Demo code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":file").filestyle({
        classButton: "btn btn-primary"
    });

    $("#getFileName").click(function () {
        alert($("input[type=file]").val());
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8CpnH/

### EDIT

If you want to get the full path name you'll face a "problem" not related to the plugin, but to browser security reasons.

You can check some related and deep questions on SO like [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)